# Slow insert statements on SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-administration

A single insert statement is taking, occasionally, more than 2 seconds. The inserts are potentially concurrent, as it depends on our site traffic which can result in 200 inserts per minute.

The table has more than 150M rows, 4 indexes and is accessed using a simple select statement for reporting purposes.

SHOW INDEX FROM ouptut
[image: SHOW INDEX FROM output]

How to speed up the inserts considering that all indexes are required?

Comment: An index increases the insertion time. (More work to do...)

Comment: Any triggers involved?

Comment: @jarlh: Yes its the problem. That's why need a solution :)
No triggers involved.

Comment: You can't really have it both ways, either no index for fast insertion or indexed for better selects- play about with the number of indexes you have, do you have large indexes that include half of the table fields, do you have unused indexes etc...

Comment: @dbajtr: There must be some solution or alternative to overcome this. I've only 3 indexed columns and that too is required.

Comment: Please add more info so that other users can imagine your scenario. You can add complete table structure, How the table is accessed, i.e. by a real time application or via batch?  What does `huge` means here? Be more specific.

Comment: @Vivek: Table has 12 columns that cannot be broken into small tables further. The table is accessed using a simple select statement for reporting purposes. It's not a real-time app but we have got good traffic on the site so the inserts statements can be 200 per minute. But due to slow inserts, it is delaying the further processing after storing into the table. 
huge means more than 15crore rows in the table.

Comment: SHOW INDEX FROM table_name would be quite helpful and give us a clue on table/index volumes and cardinality.  Please post.

Comment: If your add details to your original question, instead of adding details in comments, would be much easier to read.

Comment: @WilsonHauck: https://image.prntscr.com/image/2TkMad_7R8ahwC9_eRi-Cg.png

Comment: Are you using auto increment for that Id column?

Comment: You said the table is accessed by a single SQL statement, so, do you really need all those indexes? Could you check/post the EXPLAIN output for that select?

Comment: @vikashsharma  The SHOW INDEX FROM table_name does not look anything like the example from refman 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-index.html  
Could your repost when available?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided many details but it seems like you need partitions.

An insertion operation in an database index has, in general, an O(logN) time complexity where N is the number of rows in the table. If your table is really huge even logN may become too much.

So, to address that scalability issue you can make use of index partitions to transparently split up your table indexes in smaller internal pieces and reduce that N without changing your application or SQL scripts.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-overview.html

[EDIT]

Considering information initially added in the comments and now updated in the question itself.

- 200 potentially concurrent inserts per minute
- 4 indexes
- 1 select for reporting purposes

There are a few not mutually exclusive improvements:

- Check the output of EXPLAIN for that SELECT and remove indexes not being used, or, otherwise, combine them in a single index.
- Make the inserts in batch

  - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-optimization.html
  - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html
- Partitioning still an option.

Alternatively, change your approach: save the data to a nosql database like redis and populate the mysql table asynchronously for reporting purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @olivecoder. I am looking for the partitioning as you shared. Will let you know my findings here. 
I've shared few details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46036600/slow-insert-statements#comment79036358_46036600